# VS08-WIN7-What account does ASP.NET web server run as?

Tags: .net, trace

VS08-WIN7-What account does VS08's ASP.NET development web server run as? I am trying to write to a log file.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf(lifecycleSwitch.TraceInfo,
    string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}", DateTime.Now, "Page",
    this.GetType().Name, "Page_Load", "Start", User.Identity.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Request.Url.PathAndQuery, Session.SessionID));
    Response.Write(Environment.UserName);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf(lifecycleSwitch.TraceInfo,
    string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}", DateTime.Now, "Page",
    this.GetType().Name, "Page_Load", "Start", User.Identity.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Request.Url.PathAndQuery, Session.SessionID));
}
```

But, the log file keeps displaying empty. Is it a permissions issue on the folder where the logfile lives? Here is the corresponding web.config section.

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<switches>
  <add name="Lifecycle" value="4"/>
</switches>
<trace autoflush="false" indentsize="0">
  <listeners>
    <add name="LifecycleLog" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
         initializeData="C:\Logs\lifecycle.log"/>
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

Comment: can you show the trace section in your web.config ?

Comment: Which web server are you using?  The built-in visual studio development server (Cassini)? IIS Express?  Or IIS 7.5 (if you install IIS via the control panel)?

Comment: The built-in VS08 dev web server(Cassisni).

Answer (score 2):

the web server runs with your identity

Comment: do you mean System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity? Because that is what I get when I do Response.Write(Page.User.Identity); Is that thing assignable to the folder to be given writes permissions???

Comment: `Page.User.Identity` is not the identity of the process, but the identity of the logged user (which can be the same). To get the identity of the process, use `System.Threading.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`